# VBA ADO Recordset .Copyfromrecordset long runtime

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am searching for VBA code that can fix this run-time build-up, or suggestions on what could be causing this.

I am running a VBA script that retrieves data from a SQL Server database using ADODB. I have ran a test for run-time on the line that copies the data into my excel sheet. The run time is varying; however, I have found that run-time ranges between 3-30 seconds for the line:

```
Sheets(1).range("A8").CopyFromRecordset recordSet
```

The data in the record set consists of 300 rows, and 13 columns.

One thing I find strange is that when the excel application is closed and reopened, the run-time seems to reset to normal.

Here is an idea of what the runtime is like per test of the .copyfromrecordset line:

- Test 1: 3 seconds
- Test 2: 3 seconds
- Test 3: 3 seconds
- Test 4: 5 seconds
- Test 5: 5 seconds
- Test 6: 6 seconds
- Test 7: 7 seconds
- Test 8: 6 seconds
- Test 9: 8 seconds
- Test 9: 10 seconds
- ...
- Test 20: 24 seconds

I ran tests on local commands such as formatting cell width/heights and these run-times are constant at 1 or 2 seconds.

Maybe I am using the recordset incorrectly, or if no solution is found I will just reduce database calls, which prevents me from having up-to-date data.

I have gone through and checked for any unclosed recordset objects which I thought might have been the issue, but nothing is left open.

```
Function Query(SQL As String)

Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
Dim Field As ADODB.Field
Set recordSet = New ADODB.recordSet
recordSet.Open SQL, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdTxt

If recordSet.State Then

    'seting up table headers
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To recordSet.Fields.Count - 1
    Sheets(1).Cells(7, 1 + i).value = recordSet.Fields(i).name
    Next i
    Sheets(1).range("A7:M7").Font.Bold = True

    t = Now()
    'insert recordset data into cells
    Sheets(1).range("A8").CopyFromRecordset recordSet
    MsgBox Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")**

    'close recordset object
    recordSet.Close
    Set recordSet = Nothing
End If


End Function
```

Database Connection

```
Function ConnectToDB(Server As String, Database As String) As Boolean

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error Resume Next

    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Integrated Security=SSPI; Data Source=" & Server & "; Initial Catalog=" & Database & ";"
    Conn.Open

    If Conn.State = 0 Then
        ConnectToDB = False
    Else
        ConnectToDB = True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: This can't be all your code. Where do you setup the connection?

Comment: @kyle added the db connection function

Comment: You never close your connection. If I'm not mistaken, you continue to open new connections each time you make a call which bogs down your workbook.

Comment: I will check to see if I closed the connection to the database. Hopefully i didn't miss this cause I know how obvious this is... ;(

Comment: As alternative you can try the Data tab > From Other Sources to see if that is faster or Power Query

Comment: Conn.close is being reached in the debugger for every connection that is opened.

Comment: I have extensive experience (over several years) with `ADODB` and `.CopyFromRecordset` is the fastest method there is to get the recordset into your file. It never took me more than 1-2 seconds to run this line (even for several thousand rows or data in return). Closing the connections is not a problem as they get automatically closed when the function is terminated ([scope of variables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693)). Are you sure that this one line is taking so long (and not running the query)? I don't see any time tracking in your function for that line.

Comment: Also, are you cleaning your sheet before pasting new data? If you are just inserting (or appending) each time new data then the `.UsedRange` steadily increases and it might be a performance problem with the sheet. Make sure that `.ScreenUpdating` and `.Calculation` are turned off when you paste and / or that the sheet (to which you are pasting) is not visible. I sure hope you don't have any events on that sheet. Otherwise, you should turn off events too for the process. Is there any protection on the sheet or shapes / controls / buttons / etc. ?

Comment: I added the code for the time into the question.
I also checked for screen updating... etc, it had no effect on runtime. The only thing that could lower runtime was closing the application.

Comment: Is there anything you can give us to replicate the problem? Using the above code with a standard query such as `select * from sys.columns cross apply (select * from sys.columns) as c` - resulting in almost a million rows in my case and running the function several times (with a clean-up in between using `sheet1.Rows.Delete` I was not able to replicate your problems.

Comment: Ill make a new project with similar code and see if I can replicate it.

Comment: I made a new application and it had a 0 second run-time consistently. So something is making this slow that is outside of the scope of this post. I will post back if I find it cause I am curious now.

Comment: I voted to close this post as the problem cannot be reproduced. Once you have located the culprit you can post a new question or vote to reopen this post with new insights. If you want you may also upload the file some place and I might have a look at it. But until then this post is not helpful (with an irreproducible problem). If you prefer, you can also remove this post yourself (for now).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  By stepping one line at a time through some code, I isolated two instances of the CopyFromRecordset command taking around 5 - 6 minutes to complete when dealing with a recordset with around 30K - 40K records.  This was a massive workbook with many formulae.  Adding the line:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

to the beginning of the macro reduced the time of the whole process to only 30 - 40 seconds from around 10 - 12 minutes.

This works by preventing Excel from trying to recalculate the values of every formula in the massive workbook with each of the tens of thousands of records being copied into the worksheet.  There is also a line already later in the macro that returns the behavior back to default with:

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```